# How can I, in Javascript, get my a JSON list of my Google Photos album?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-js-client, google-photos-api

I am trying to build an Express.js based website which, when I navigate to a certain page, grabs a list of albums, links, ids, etc. I have a service account with all permissions. My Javascript is:

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  config.serviceAccount.client_id,
  config.oAuthclientSecret,
  config.oAuthCallbackUrl
);

google.options({auth: oauth2Client});

function getAlbumList(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums"
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("making xhr")
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    }
    xhr.addEventListener('error',function(){
        console.log(xhr.statusMessage)
        console.log("xhr.status is ", xhr.status )
        console.log("ERROR");
    })
    xhr.addEventListener('timeout',function(){
        console.log("SERVER TIMEOUT")
    })
    // Sending our request 
    xhr.send();

}
```

However, I never even get a response back. I do have a service account, and my credential is:

```
{  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myProj",
  "private_key_id": "8dxxxxxx46",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQExxxxxxxxxQ==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "ihfphotograb@myproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "10xxxxxxxxx6451",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/proj%40myproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

I've looked at [this](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/list) but they don't tell you how to get a token and when I looked at the network tab to see the request and params going thru. I do have `const {google} = require('googleapis')` but I don't know how to get that token.

I want the service app to do all the authentication and so my website's visitors can see the photos without authenticating.

Comment: _"get my a JSON"_?  What were you intending to actually write in your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Supported Authorization protocols](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authorization)

[image]

You are trying to use a service account, which is not supported by this api. You are also trying to use a service account with JavaScript which is also not supported.   You need to go and create [web application credetinals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU&t=1s)

You will need to switch to using Oauth2.

There is a sample in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/list?apix=true)  which shows how to do this.  (As of November 2022 this sample has not been updated to take into account for the new identity model.  Check below for a working example.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Photos API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Photos API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
    const API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/photoslibrary/v1/rest';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly';

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            await listAlbums();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print metadata for first 10 Albums.
     */
    async function listAlbums() {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await gapi.client.photoslibrary.albums.list({
                'pageSize': 10,
                'fields': 'albums(id,title)',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
        }
        const albums = response.result.albums;
        if (!albums || albums.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No albums found.';
            return;
        }
        // Flatten to string to display
        const output = albums.reduce(
            (str, album) => `${str}${album.title} (${album.id}\n`,
            'albums:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the sample for you to take into account the new identity model. Hope this helps.    I have notified google about the issues with the official sample.

Comment: thank you very much. How would I write this in a .js file that automatically chooses to authorize w/ the same user and api keys so that, say, when someone goes to the "photos" page of my site, they can be guaranteed to always be served the latest photo albums?

Comment: If what you are trying to do is grant others access to your own google photos then this is not something that can be done with JavaScript.  You could do it with a server sided language like node.js by storing your own refresh token and displaying the data returned to all users.   But client side JavaScript does not support refresh tokens.   And this api does not support service accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the token to your API request, otherwise, you'll get `401` `unauthorized` error.

Add the following code at the bottom of your index.js file, use your client Id and Secret instead of placeholders:

```
/*  Google AUTH  */
 
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'our-google-client-id';
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'our-google-client-secret';
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      userProfile=profile;
      return done(null, userProfile);
  }
));
 
app.get('/auth/google', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));
 
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/error' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect success.
    res.redirect('/success');
  });
```

You can have a look more detailed sample code [here](https://blog.loginradius.com/engineering/google-authentication-with-nodejs-and-passportjs/).

Comment: can I put what you're doing in the `app.get` calls inside an XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange call? or should this really all be in my express app's main.js, its `app.get("/page-this-should-occur-on", async function(req,res){
        var $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('views/pages/page-this-should-occur-on.ejs'));
 var pagePath = req.path
 photofetch.getAlbumList();
 res.render("index",{page:$.html(),pagename:pagePath})
})`?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to use `HTMLHTTPRequest`? If not, you'd better go with the sample code I have provided.

Comment: will making a new instance of express screw my current running instance of express up? The way this website will work is that once someone navigates to a certain page, ultmately all albums will show their thumbnail. But my Express app deals with page paths

Comment: What do you mean by screw? I don't get your question

Comment: https://github.com/LoginRadius/engineering-blog-samples/tree/master/NodeJs/GoogleAuthenticationPassport
Here's the full working code

Comment: If you are not familiar with `ejs`, you can use other view template engine, like `swig`

Comment: alright @dream-bold, it appears to be working, tho how do I get down the json I need of the albums' ids, urls, etc.?

Comment: Just send a request to `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums` and process the data as you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249916/discussion-between-dream-bold-and-user311302).